# Angular 2 class design

Tags: angular, class, typescript

I have access to an API that returns a json object containing three keys, "success", "data" and "pagination". My user class reflects the structure of a particular user, that prevent me for returning the whole object containing also pagination and status because it expects a users array. 
I'd like to return the whole object from the API but still using angular classes. Should i modify the class to reflect the structure of the return object or are there any better alternatives?. Thanks in advance

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 8,
            "username": "epierce7",
            "password": "HuLYyxPxs",
            "email": "ereyes7@businessweek.com"
        }
    ],
    "pagination": {
        "page_count": 99,
        "current_page": 1,
        "has_next_page": true,
        "has_prev_page": false,
        "count": 981,
        "limit": null
    }
```

This is my user class

```
export class User {
  id: number;
  username: string;
  email: string;
  token: string;
}
```

This is the function inside a service that makes the call to the API:

```
  getUsers(): Promise<User[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.usersUrl, {headers: this.headers})
               .toPromise()
               .then(response => response.json().data as User[]) //I'd like to return the whole object, not only object.data
               .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Comment: First, User should really be an interface, not a class. But no, you shouldn't change User. You should define *another* interface, containing a success property, a pagination property, and a data property, of type Array<User>.

Comment: Defining another interface seems the logic way to go. Thanks a lot.